# Is the martingale property preserved by taking weak$^*$-limits?

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, probability-theory, martingales

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F)$ be a measurable space, $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb R^d$ a $\mathcal F$-measurable map. Let $(\mathcal F_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}$ be a filtration of $\mathcal F$ such that $\mathcal F=\sigma(\mathcal F_k\mid k\in\mathbb N).$ Assume that $\mathcal F_k$ is generated by a countable partition for every $k\in\mathbb N.$ Let $(\mathbb Q_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence of probability measures which is weak$^*$-convergent to a probability measure $\mathbb Q.$

The weak$^*$-topology is the weakest topology such that all the linear functionals $L_Z:\mathbb P\mapsto \int_\Omega Zd\mathbb P$ for $Z:Ω\rightarrow\mathbb R$ $\mathcal F$-measurable and bounded, are continuous.

Assume that for all $k\in\mathbb N$ we have $$E_{\mathbb Q_k}[X\mid\mathcal F_k]=0.$$ Can we conclude that $$\ E_{\mathbb Q'}[X\mid\mathcal F]=0$$ for some probability measure $\mathbb Q'$ which is equivalent to $\mathbb Q$? (maybe this works even for $\mathbb Q$ itself). Note that by Doob's martingale convergence theorem, we have $$\lim_{l\rightarrow\infty}E_{\mathbb Q_k}[X\mid\mathcal F_l]= E_{\mathbb Q_k}[X\mid\mathcal F]$$ in $L^1$ and $\mathbb Q_k$-a.s., for each $k\in\mathbb N.$ I am also not sure if weak$^*$-convergence implies that $$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} E_{\mathbb Q_k}[X\mid\mathcal F]=E_{\mathbb Q}[X\mid\mathcal F]$$ $\mathbb Q$-a.s. or in $L^1(\mathbb Q)?$

Comment: It is not clear to me what you mean by weak*-convergence.  Are the test functions bounded or vanishing at infinity?  Probabilists refer to the former as convergence in distribution and the latter as vague convergence.  At the absolute minimum, you are going to need uniform integrability of these measures.  If you have that, then the last statement you wrote is easy to show.  If not, then there are easy counterexamples with a trivial sigma-algebra (take anything positive which converges a.s. but not in L^1).  The first question is similarly true with extra hypotheses but not without them.

Comment: @Chris Janjigian: Thanks a lot for your comment. What are test functions "vanishing at infinity" on a measurable space?

Comment: I was implicitly assuming you were working on locally compact Polish space, since that is fairly standard in probability.  I am confused, then.  What does weak* convergence mean outside of a topological space?

Comment: So I added what I mean by the weak$^*$-topology...So as you said, the test functions are bounded and measurable. Could you still clarify your argument using uniform integrability?

Comment: I think what you are calling weak* convergence is typically called strong convergence of measures in the literature.  Unfortunately, I know nothing about that and my previous comment is not relevant, sorry.  I was assuming your test functions were continuous.  If they were continuous on say $\mathbb{R}^d$, then you could use a Skorokhod representation theorem to realize the sequence as an a.s. limit on a single probability space and uniform integrability would imply $L^1$ convergence.

Comment: Ok, still I would appreciate it if you can write your previous comment as an answer in the case where it is assumed the test functions are continuous...